# What is necessary for a StyleableProperty to actually listen to changes in a css file?

Tags: java, css, javafx

This is related very much to [this question of Neil Benn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45681021/styleableproperty-in-javafx-css).

When I build a StyleableProperty using the StyleablePropertyFactory following the steps Neil provided, I get a property that can be set from the fxml file, but which ignores the css completely.

His solution was to listen to any changes of the css and redraw his object when that happens (at least that's my understanding so far).

Since I can't get this to work **I would appreciate any tip on what to add to this (somewhat minimal) example to make it work with its css file**.

## Minimal Working example

My custom JavaFX Control: StyleablePane.java

```
package projects.styleableproperty;

import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.css.StyleableProperty;
import javafx.css.StyleablePropertyFactory;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundFill;
import javafx.scene.layout.CornerRadii;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

public class StyleablePane extends Pane {
    private static final StyleablePropertyFactory<StyleablePane> FACTORY = new StyleablePropertyFactory<>(
            StyleablePane.getClassCssMetaData());

    public StyleablePane() {
        // keeping background color same as fill color for testing purpose
        fillProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(newValue, new CornerRadii(0), new Insets(0))));
        });
    }

    // Fill Property //
    private final StyleableProperty<Color> fill = FACTORY
            .createStyleableColorProperty(this, "fill", "-fx-fill", svgPane -> svgPane.fill);

    public Color getFill() {
        return fill.getValue();
    }

    public void setFill(Color fill) {
        this.fill.setValue(fill);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public ObservableValue<Color> fillProperty() {

        return (ObservableValue<Color>) fill;
    }
}
```

An FXML file using this custom control: Styleable.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import projects.styleableproperty.StyleablePane?>
<?import java.lang.String?>
<AnchorPane prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="300.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.2-internal" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <StyleablePane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" styleClass="a-green-one"/>
   </children>
   <stylesheets>
      <String fx:value="/css/Styleable.css"/>
   </stylesheets>
</AnchorPane>
```

A simple style sheet: Styleable.css

```
.a-green-one {
    -fx-fill: aquamarine;
}
```

Small application to run the whole bunch:

```
package projects.styleableproperty;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class StyleableExperiment extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        AnchorPane rootPane = null;
        try {
            rootPane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Styleable.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(rootPane);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

What I would like to see:

[image: aquamarine square in dialog box]

What I currently see:

[image: empty dialog box]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to override the `getCssMetaData()` method in `StyleablePane`:

```
@Override
public List<CssMetaData<? extends Styleable, ?>> getCssMetaData() {
    return FACTORY.getCssMetaData();
}
```

While it's not necessary to make it work, it's good practice to provide a static `getClassCssMetaData()` method returning the same list (hat-tip to [@slaw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6395627/slaw) for this):

```
public static List<CssMetaData<? extends Styleable, ?>> getClassCssMetaData() {
    return FACTORY.getCssMetaData();
}
```

From the [documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/css/CssMetaData.html):

> The purpose of `getClassCssMetaData()` is to allow sub-classes to easily
>   include the `CssMetaData` of some ancestor.

Note that your instantiation of the `FACTORY` is not quite correct. From the documentation for `StyleablePropertyFactory`:

> The constructor is passed the `CssMetaData` of the **parent** class of `<S>`

(my emphasis), so you should have

```
private static final StyleablePropertyFactory<StyleablePane> FACTORY = new StyleablePropertyFactory<>(
        Pane.getClassCssMetaData());
```

The complete class should be

```
import java.util.List;

import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.css.CssMetaData;
import javafx.css.Styleable;
import javafx.css.StyleableProperty;
import javafx.css.StyleablePropertyFactory;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundFill;
import javafx.scene.layout.CornerRadii;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

public class StyleablePane extends Pane {
    private static final StyleablePropertyFactory<StyleablePane> FACTORY = new StyleablePropertyFactory<>(
            Pane.getClassCssMetaData());

    public StyleablePane() {
        // keeping background color same as fill color for testing purpose
        fillProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(newValue, new CornerRadii(0), new Insets(0))));
        });
    }

    @Override
    public List<CssMetaData<? extends Styleable, ?>> getCssMetaData() {
        return FACTORY.getCssMetaData();
    }

    public static List<CssMetaData<? extends Styleable, ?>> getClassCssMetaData() {
        return FACTORY.getCssMetaData();
    }

    // Fill Property //
    private final StyleableProperty<Color> fill = FACTORY
            .createStyleableColorProperty(this, "fill", "-fx-fill", svgPane -> svgPane.fill);

    public Color getFill() {
        return fill.getValue();
    }

    public void setFill(Color fill) {
        this.fill.setValue(fill);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public ObservableValue<Color> fillProperty() {

        return (ObservableValue<Color>) fill;
    }
}
```

Comment: And to follow convention there should also be a static `getClassCssMetaData()` returning the same list, though it's not necessary to make the CSS work.

Comment: Thank you very much. This did the trick.
@Slaw: what is the advantage of the aditional method besides being a convention?

Comment: @Chaoskatze I incorporated a note explaining the `static` method.

Comment: @James_D: Thank you very much. For some reason, adding the static method leads to a NullPointerException for me with JavaFX 8. Should I open a new question for this?

Comment: @Chaoskatze Yes; fixed - the argument to the `StyleablePropertyFactory` was wrong: you should pass the `CssMetaData` of the *parent* class, not the current class.

Comment: Very good addition with the Factory implementation! You really helped me out of my misery here! Wish I could upvote your anwer more.